# Databound Listbox in Wizard loses selections on page change

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, wizard

I downloaded the source code from [this tutorial](http://www.differentpla.net/content/2005/02/implementing-wizard-c-part-2) after a failed attempt to make my own Wizard. The control works great and is integrating nicely into my program. I have one minor problem, though. I have a page that has both a databound ListBox and a databound TreeView. When changing to the next or previous page, the TreeView maintains its selections but the ListBox does not. Instead, it appears to update itself (judging by the flash). How can I prevent this from happening and maintain the user's selections?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh! Serves me right for re-using code that I haven't looked at in a couple of months. Turns out the TreeView is not data bound but populated from a Value Object. I modified the ListBox to use its own VO and now it works perfectly. Kind of a complicated way of doing things but whatever works, right?